# Can't compile a program that calls tgkill

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kill

I'm trying to write a program that uses tgkill to send a signal to a specific thread, but whenever I compile it with gcc I get an error about an undefined reference to 'tgkill'. I tried compiling with -lpthread but it didn't help. I've googled and googled and can't come up with any answers.  How do I get it to compile??

Comment: Why use old linux-libc-only functions nowadays? POSIX threads is the way to go, and you probably have support for it, since you mention the pthread library. But if you have most of your code finished, try calling it through syscall(2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `tgkill()` manpage:

> Glibc does not provide wrappers for
>   these system calls; call them using
>   syscall(2).

Comment: Thanks, I read the manpage but didn't read the whole thing...lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use something like this instead.

```
tgid=getpid();  
tid=gettid();  
syscall(SYS_tgkill, tgid, tid, signalname));
```

Comment: gettid() also does not have a wrapper unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

As noted in another answer, glibc does not provide wrappers for `tkill()` or `tgkill()`.

Instead, you're supposed to use `pthread_kill()`.

Comment: pthread_kill is not a direct replacement for tgkill, in particular, pthread IDs used by pthread_kill are not the same as lightweight process ids used by tgkill. Use syscall(SYS_tgkill)