# Library include with tkill

Tags: c, linux, header, kill

I tried use [tkill](https://linux.die.net/man/2/tkill) ,to kill some thread with c code .

What are the library I need to include to use this function?

Running on linux ubuntu

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
   tkill(123,9);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code as you show it? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is I need to include library to make `tkill` works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't compile a program that calls tgkill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5374960/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You neeed `syscall(SYS_tkill, ThePid, TheSignal)`.

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <signal.h>
int main()
{
    //kills self:
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    syscall(SYS_tkill,tid,SIGTERM); 
    return 0;
}
```

Glibc has had a policy of not including wrappers for non-POSIX syscalls.
They may be changing it in current/future versions but using the generic `syscall` syscall-making function should always work on Linux.